# Problem to acces shared folder in Ubuntu 14.04 from Yosemite

Tags: permissions, nautilus, samba, ntfs

I have a problem to acces my shared folder in Ubuntu 14.04 from a Yosemite machine. 
I get
"**The operation can’t be completed because the original item for “” can’t be found.**"

so, i went through all the steps in command line to install samba, configure it, configure smb.conf, i think i'm fine there.

then on my mac i see my ubuntu computer, I see my shared folder, but if i doulbe click it without login in, I get : 
"The operation can’t be completed because the original item for “SHARE” can’t be found."
And if I log in, ("connect as" in macosx), then I get the same error message again.

I noticed that the permissions to this folder in nautilus are none for the group and others.
When i try, in command line or through the GUI, to change those permissions from group and others, it doesn't affect anything and the permissions seem to always come back to "none". Can it be the knot in my problem ?

Oh, and this could be important too:
the folder I try to share on my Ubuntu machine is on an external NTFS hard-drive. Maybe I just can'T change permissions on a NTFS drive?

thanks in advance...

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! What happens if you try to access the shared folder with another Ubuntu system (Or a Live Ubuntu media on your MAC?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the permissions but I have a mac and have had similar problems connecting to a windows share; after research the version of samba used in OSX is old and has some bugs.  I cannot connect to this share by name although I can see it in finder.

If I connect to the share via (Go -> Connect to Server) in the finder menu bar and enter the **direct IP address** of the other computer (ie **smb://192.168.1.101**) it will connect fine.

I could never confirm the exact cause (I couldn't play around with the server settings or the share names) but I remember one possible solution was to shorten the path (to get around a bug from old samba code).